# Why is the focus on half open intervals?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am studying measure theory, more specifically the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.
Why is there such a focus on half open intervals rather than just closed or open intervals?

Comment: Your question needs *way* more context to have a meaningful answer.

Comment: @user No, the question makes perfect sense as asked.

Comment: It really depends on the way of teaching. I don't recall learning stuff involving half-open intervals. You might mention the book that you are using, because it is not true in all approaches.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Folland, for example, in the section on Borel measures on $\Bbb R$.  (Thn: If $f$ is increasing then there exists a Borel measure $\mu$ with $\mu((a,b])=f(b)-f(a)$.) The point is that the collection of finite unions of half-open intervals is an algebra; so we can define our purported measure on half-open intervals, prove one technical lemma to the effect that we actually have a premeasure, and then invoke Caratheodory's theorem on extending a premeasure on an algebra to a measure on the sigma-algebra generated by the algebra.

Comment: @user It's already been established that there are other approaches! I much prefer Rudin, in fact. It doesn't follow from that that the OP's question requires more context for a meaningful answer. Look. Say someone asked why there was such a focus on nets in topology, and you'd never heard of nets. Would you conclude on the basis of the fact that _you_ never heard of nets that it was a bad question? Or would you assume that there was such a thing as a treatment of topology with a focus on nets, and let someone familiar with such a treatment explain?

Comment: @user And would you take comments from someone who'd never head of nets as evidence of "confusion"? Nobody who's seen a treatment of Borel measures on $\Bbb R$ based on half-open intervals is going to be the slightest bit confused by the OP's question. Comments from people who are simply unaware of the topic the OP is talking about strike me as... never mind.

Comment: @user More context. Suppose he'd said "in the chapter in Folland on Borel measures on $\Bbb R$". _How_ exactly would that improve the question? It would not help anyone who was not familiar with that sort of treatment. And it's not necessary for anyone who is.

Comment: @user Or, to put the same point yet another way: you say " that's why I was asking for more context". If in fact you'd asked for more context I would not have commented on your comment. You didn't ask for more context, you _stated_ that more context was _needed_ for a meaningful answer. That was not so - the fact that I gave a meaningful answer proves it's not so.

Comment: @user You're skirting around a question I asked without answering it. _How_ would specifying that section in Folland be more helpful? It's clear you're not familiar with that section in Folland (and I don't see anything rude about saying that,nobody's familar with everything). So I don't see how it would have helped you give an answer.

Comment: @user I've asked the question twice and you haven't answered. I didn't ask what would happen without more context - we've seen that. _How_ would his including more context have helped you answer? (And what's rude about suggesting you didn't understand the question, given that you keep saying you didn't understand the question?)

Answer (score 3):

Because the collection of finite unions of half-open intervals is an *algebra* (closed under complements, finite unions and finite intersections).

(That's assuming of course we're talking about only one flavor of half-open intervals, for example $[a,b)$ but not $(a,b]$, and assuming we allow $\pm\infty$ as endpoints.)

To state what I thought was obvious but evidently isn't: On the other hand, the collection of finite unions of closed intervals (for example) is not an algebra. We need an algebra in order to be able to apply a certain theorem of Caratheodory. The algebra consisting of finite unions of half-open intervals has a particularly simple description, making the application simple.

Comment: "That's assuming..." So, the question does not make perfect sense as asked.

Comment: What if we were talking about (a,b]? How does that change things?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No, it was "That's assuming, of course...". Anyone who's familiar with a treatment of measure theory on $\Bbb R$ that emphasizes half-open intervals already _knows_ that only one flavor is used; the comment was needed only for readers who really don't know the prerequisites and hence were puzzled by my making a statement that on the face of it was obviously false.

Comment: in particular, closed intervals are an algebra, as are open intervals, so the question of at what point this is "such a focus" still requires clarification.\

Comment: Which is *exactly* why the question is inadequate - because it is not true that "the focus" is, in general, on half-open intervals. That is a particular approach at a particular point in a measure theory class, not a universal teaching component of measure theory.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No, the closed intervals are not an algebra. The finite unions of closed intervals are not an algebra (for example the complement of $[0,1]$ is not a finite union of closed intervals.) The fact that finite unions of half-open intervals _are_ an algebra is needed to apply that theorem of Cartheodory.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So it should have been "the focus, in those treatments in which there is such a focus".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Or: What section of measure theory is it in? Or what book? Your comment above gave a useful context (Pollard, chapter on Borel sets.) The OPs question did not.

Comment: @thomasandrews The thing is I dont know how to change the question because there are unknowns which I dont know of and I have to start somewhere to build my knowledge. So I dont know how to add context to the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No. Foland, section on Borel measures on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Aljabra Either $(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$ would work just fine. If we include both things don't work out so simply.